# How do I change datatype in Program?

Tags: python

I am working on a program that takes a column from a csv file and averages the sales data, but I am getting an error: "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"

I changed the column in the csv file to numbers and I still get the error.

```
from csv import reader
opened_file = open('Catalog.csv')
read_file = reader(opened_file)
catalog_data = list(read_file)


sales_data = []
for stuff in catalog_data:
price = stuff[11]
manufacturer = stuff[7]

if manufacturer == 'HASBRO':
    sales_data.append(price)

avg_sales = sum(sales_data) / len(sales_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The int function appened doesn't work:

```
from csv import reader
opened_file = open('Catalog.csv')
read_file = reader(opened_file)
catalog_data = list(read_file)


sales_data = []
for sales in catalog_data:
    price = int(sales[11])
    manufacturer = sales[7]

    if manufacturer == 'HASBRO':
        sales_data.append(int(price))


avg_sales = sum(sales_data) / len(sales_data)
```

Comment: what about the `int()` function doesn't work? does it give an error message?

Answer (score 2):

use casting like below for price

```
price = float(stuff[11])
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're reading in from a CSV file, all the values are strings.

```
price = stuff[11]
```

At this point, `price` is a string. So when you go:

```
sales_data.append(price)`
```

`sales_data` is being populated with a list of strings.

When you eventually call `sum(sales_data)`, the `sum` function fails because it's assuming that `sales_data` is populated with numeric values.

To remedy this, simply cast the price data to an appropriate value, like so:

```
price = float(stuff[11])
```

Note that if `float`ing point values can lose precision, so it's generally not recommended to use float values to store currency values. If precision is important, consider using the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module.

Comment: Thats the best answer IMO.